# Rank racers based on start and end times

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, pseudocode

Question: You have the start time, end time and index number of racers in a race. You need to tell the rank of each racer. The rank is calculated as following: if racer B starts after racer A but finishes before racer A, then the rank of racer A increases by 1.

Example input:

```
Index     Start Time     End time   
0         100            170    
1          80            150
2         120            165
3         110            145
```

Output:

```
Index     Rank
2         0
3         0
1         1
0         2
```

I know I could use nested loop and compare and rank them but still not 100% sure. Can someone help me with writing pseudo code for this problem in time complexities of O(n^2) and O(n log n)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
Index     Start Time     End time   
0         100            170    
1          80            150
2         120            165
3         110            145
```

Order by all instances of time ascending.

```
(80, "start", 1)
(100, "start", 0)
(110, "start", 3)
(120, "start", 2)
(145, "end", 3)
(150, "end", 1)
(165, "end", 2)
(170, "end", 0)
```

Traverse the time list:

```
80: 
current_racers = {1}

100:
current_racers = {1, 0}

110:
current_racers = {1, 0, 3}

120:
current_racers = {1, 0, 3, 2}

145:
current_racers = {1, 0, X, 2}

Racers 1 and 0 started
before racer 3 so their rank
increases by 1 when 3 is removed.

150:
current_racers = {X, 0, X, 2}
No racers started before racer
1 so no other ranks are changed
when they are removed.

165:
current_racers = {X, 0, X, X}
Racer 0 is before racer 2
so their rank is increased
when racer 2 is removed.

Ranks
0: 2
1: 1
2: 0
3: 0
```

During the traversal, insert the racers into a fenwick tree that's arranged for range updates and point queries. (I guess the "insertion" would just be to record their index in the tree. The tree itself just contains ranks associated with each of its indexes.)

Insert the starting racer at the next index, always ahead of the last insertion. When a racer ends, output the rank stored at their index, and increase by one the interval [0, current_racer). It doesn't matter that they stay in the tree because they won't affect racers again. When only one racer is left in the tree, output their rank.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that you can do it in O(n^2). This is real code rather than pseudocode, but it should be understandable.

```js
var data = [
  { start:100, end:170, rank:0 },
  { start: 80, end:150, rank:0 },
  { start:120, end:165, rank:0 },
  { start:110, end:145, rank:0 }
];

var operations = 0;

for (var a in data) {
  for (var b in data) {
    // "if racer B starts after racer A but finishes before racer A"
    if (data[b].start > data[a].start &&
        data[b].end < data[a].end) {
      // "then the rank of racer A increases by 1"
      data[a].rank++;
    }
    operations++;
  }  
}

console.log("Performed " + operations + " operations for " + data.length + " items.");
console.log(data);
```

That will output:

```
Performed 16 operations for 4 items.
[
  {
    "start": 100,
    "end": 170,
    "rank": 2
  },
  {
    "start": 80,
    "end": 150,
    "rank": 1
  },
  {
    "start": 120,
    "end": 165,
    "rank": 0
  },
  {
    "start": 110,
    "end": 145,
    "rank": 0
  }
]
```

In this case O(n^2) would be O(4^2), which is 16.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to reduce time complexity from O(n^2) even further to O(nlogn)?